# Rename the [geothermal-heat] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [geothermal-heat](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geothermal-heat) seems a bit tautologous. I suppose the idea is 'geothermal energy for heating'. But it's not a super-popular tag (only 15 uses), and some questions (e.g. yesterday's [Is there a correlation between hot springs and earthquakes?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4513)) are about geothermal but not about heating. I added the tag to that question, but it doesn't seem quite right; a more general [geothermal](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geothermal) tag would be better.

No idea what the process is for changing a tag name, but thought I'd start here. Cheers!

Comment: Sounds fair enough too

Comment: Is there something "geothermal" that doesn't involve heat? You know, the therm part? Like, I see "geothermal" and "geothermal-heat" as the exact same...

Answer (score 2):

I agree that geothermal-heat tag doesn't really apply to the question referenced, but this site only has **one** tag relating to geothermal as a subject.

I think a general *geothermal* tag is required. Concerning the geothermal-heat tag either keep it as it is or change it to *geothermal-energy*. Also, would the following tags be useful:

- geothermal
- geothermal-heat or geothermal-energy
- geothermal-steam
- geothermal-hot-water
- geothermal-minerals
- geothermal-vent

Comment: I suspect only 1 tag is needed right now, but if not then I like the idea of changing *geothermal-heat* to *geothermal-energy*. I'm not sure a lot of new tags are warranted, given how few questions there are today.